# Read a multipart.file uploaded by http request with pdf library in golang

Tags: go, parsing, pdf, httprequest, multipartfile

I have tried to parse it directly but it turned the binary of the pdf so I tried this instead: copy the file content from the request into a new file that placed in the same package and read it but it turned the file is empty. Can anyone give some explanation about the logic used to solve this problem? Also let me know if you have any suggestion about the package that I can use

```
func (c *Client) HandleUpload(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    ctx, cancel := c.createContextWithTimeout(TimeoutHandleUpload)
    defer cancel()

    f, _, err := request.FormFile("data")
    if err != nil {
        c.httpError(writer, err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    err = c.ReadFile(f)
    if err != nil {
        c.httpError(writer, err)
        return
    }

    _ = httputil.WriteObj200(writer, nil)
}


func (c *Client) ReadFile(f multipart.File) (err error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    var file bytes.Buffer

    _, err = io.Copy(&buf, f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := os.WriteFile("file.pdf", file.Bytes(), 0666); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    uploadedFile, err := os.Open("file.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer uploadedFile.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(uploadedFile, &file)
    fmt.Println("file")

    absPath, err := filepath.Abs("file.pdf")
    content, err := os.ReadFile(absPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(content))
}
```

Comment: `os.Open()` and `os.WriteFile()` takes in a absolute path, you are passing a relative path. The path resolves to the root of the operating system ("/" for Linux and "c:\" for Windows), you need to use the `filepath.Abs()` function. Also another thing is that I recommend you to use `os.Create()` instead of `os.WriteFile()`

Comment: "os.Open() and os.WriteFile() takes in a absolute path" no, they just take a path.  ([example from the doc](https://pkg.go.dev/os#example-WriteFile)).  For a relative path to work, of course, the current working directory would have to be the correct location for the operation

Comment: "I have tried to parse it directly but it turned the binary of the pdf"  How is writing it to file going to change that?  Its still just bytes.  "a new file that placed in the same package" packages are a compile time, code time thing.  They are no longer relevant when running a compiled executable.  Keep in mind that unlike interpreted language, the Go executable once compiled does not need its source code to be executed.  If you're in the source package directory, that's just incidental.